# session evict method throws an exception while clear doesnt

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I am creating 2 objects of pojo class and saving it using session.save . The code is shown below

```
Student s1=new Student(1,"andrew");     
Student s2=new Student(2,"david");

session.save(s1);
session.evict(s1);
session.save(s1);
session.save(s2);
```

Here after saving the pojo object after using **evict method** throws an exception of type **duplicate primary key**

But when i am using **session.clear()** in place of **session.evict(s1)** i dont get any exception.

According to the definition of evict doesn't it result in the clearing of the pojo object from the first level session cache.

Comment: @brso05 What type means?

Comment: Try using session.flush() after the evict method and see what happens.

Comment: it is giving the same error.What i am not understanding is that why isnt evict method working

Comment: Can someone please help me on this?